# Encode file name with special characters to upload on post Http request in jmeter

Tags: http, encoding, jmeter

When I try to upload a text file with special characters in a post Http request on JMeter, those characters are replaced by "??????".

Is there a way to define UTF-8 encoding to the file name?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. Add [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to your Test Plan
4. Run the test
5. Look for `file.encoding` property under response data tab

   [image]

If what you see is different from `UTF-8` - you will need to change the setting either by adding the next line to *system.properties* file

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

or passing it via `-D` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Once done JMeter should be able to use/show non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) file names properly

References:

- [How to get and set default Character encoding or Charset in Java](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html#ixzz5z6iRLUXI)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for your answer. However it does not fix the issue maybe because the special characters for example 仮ｶあ漢字غ Ö提अ are in the name of the file and not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the above didn't help either. For me what worked was adding a combo of user defined variables and body data.

First create the data you want to send as variables in 'User Defined Variables', referencing these in the POST using $(`name_of_var`).

Then also make sure you are using 'Body Data' instead of 'Parameters' in your http request e.g...
[image: jmeter body data]

For some reason this worked for me, I think jmeter doesn't apply encoding to variables by default.